# How can I make a "SYSTEM" level service write to a root level "USB" sysfs node?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

Basically, I have a SYSTEM-level service "X" which wants to write to a USB node.
Now the USB node is 644. If I make it 646 it works fine. But 646 does not sound good.

I then created a root level script "Y" (with 777) where I just write to this USB node.
If I call "Y" from shell then it works fine.
But if the script is called from "X", then it does not work.

I cannot make "X" run as root. It's a systemd service. Can I give it exclusive right access to this USB node ?

Comment: one common way is to add the service user to the group and make permissions 664

Comment: Add some udev rule to make the device node accessible to your user and/or group? There aren't enough details here for me to suggest anything more specific than that.

Comment: @stark yes I am thinking of doing that only. Change the group to system and mode to 664.

Comment: @Hasturkun do you think I can change the group and mode from UDEV rules ?
Like if the USB node is present then change the ownership and mode